# Bean's method that returns to the previous page

Tags: jsf, cdi, back

After performing the appropriate action, the method of my bean must ensure that the browser back to the previous page. How can I handle it?

I am using the CDI Conversation.

Comment: What is the "appropriate action" ?

Comment: Enter data into the database and display it on the previous page

Comment: On a button click I suppose ?

Comment: Yes, the jsf page call a bean's method and must go back.

Comment: And what are you using for faces ? Icefaces ? Primefaces ?

Comment: And do you use faces-config.xml ?

Comment: any feedback on my answer ?

Comment: This is the solution that I already had. I was looking for how to do the operation as back in the browser. Thank you

Comment: redirect ? You can specify that in the navigation rule.

Answer (score 7):

Pass the current URI as request parameter along during navigation to the page containing that action.

```
<h:link value="Go to page containing that action" outcome="pageContainingThatAction.xhtml">
    <f:param name="from" value="#{request.requestURI}" />
</h:link>
```

*(use `#{view.viewId}` instead if you want to pass the view ID)*

Set and remember that parameter representing the URI in the view/conversation scoped managed bean.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="from" value="#{bean.from}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Finally redirect to that URI in that action method.

```
public void thatActionMethod() throws IOException {
    // ...

    externalContext.redirect(from);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After asking you a couple of question in comments, I think what you want to do is :

- On your button, specify the attribute `action` to a function in your bean that return a String.
- The String returned need to be the navigation path to the page you want to be redirected.
- If the validation is wrong on button click, then simply return null and it will stay on same page.
- Make sure you define the proper navigation rule in faces-config.xml

See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaxf.html) for how to configure navigation rules.

See [Primefaces commandButton doc](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/commandButton.html) for info on `action` tag.